# How to give maximum height as possible to views that are vertically aligned and keep these views with the same height?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have three ImageView representing cards that are vertically chained. On top of them I have a TextView and below them a Button. You can see what I mean here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G70zp.jpg

I would like the cards to be as high as possible depending on the size of the device. What's important for me is that the height of all three cards adjusts dynamically but also remains the same among them. Of course they cannot overlap with the TextView above or with the Button below either.

Comment: Share your xml please

Comment: sharing code will be good idea, can't help you without it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have 3 vertically chained items all you have to do is declare your 3 images height as match constraints or `0dp`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="This is the top text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="This is the bottom text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use Linear Layout as parent view and orientation=vertical. inside linear layout use card view. set layout_weight=1 for each card view.

Comment: This is not answering the question as OP said he is using `constraintlayout` with `vertically chained` views and he is looking for constraintlayout solution. never use nested views inside constraintlayout